# What were the obligations of prayer before Hijra?

Tags: history, salat

There are numerous well-known obligations to prayer, as established throughout the hadith literature, including rulings on the form of prayer, the daily number of prayers, praying in congregation, and where and when such prayers are to be done.

However, given that many of the hadiths in question, despite their authenticity, are not clearly dated, it is hard to know which of these obligations were in place before the first masjid was built (i.e. before the Hijra), and which of these obligations were only established afterwards.

For example, the well-known hadith of [the man who prayed badly](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/10#151) is often referenced to describe what is mandatory in regards to the form of the prayer.  The timing of this hadith, however, is likely after the Hijrah as it is narrated as taking place in the masjid itself ("*Allah's Messenger (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) **entered the mosque** and a person followed him...*")  While the man himself clearly did not know the proper form, it is not clear whether this form was commonly known or mandated previously.

Given that the revelation to the prophet began about a dozen years earlier, even without the firm political base of Medina with which to establish (and enforce) legislation, it seems there likely would've been *some* regulation, at least for one of the most *fundamental* aspects of the religion (one of the "pillars", as it were).

**Is there any information regarding which (if any) of the prayer obligations were in place *before* Hijra?**

Comment: I do not understand your point? Only because the Mosques were not made yet you doubt if Muslims were praying with all the conditions of a prayer before Hijrah? First note that Ka'abeh was a place for praying that in the first years of the prophethood of the holy prophet that the Mushrikun were not teasing him much it is recorded that the prophet, Imam Ali and the holiness Khadijah --peace be upon them-- used to pray beside Ka'bah, toward the first Qiblah (strange to people around them), and when teasing Muslims increased they started to Taqiyyah until they moved to Medina. Allah knows best.

Comment: @owari `you doubt if Muslims were praying with all the conditions of a prayer before Hijrah?` That's exactly my point; it is known that Islam (and all its rules and regulations) did not come all at once, but was revealed over twenty-odd years.  I want to know which (be it any, all, or none) of these rules and regulations were in place, pre-Hijrah, regarding prayers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are Ahadeeth that state the Five Everyday Prayer became obligated at the night the holy prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- was moved from Mecca to Beyt ul-Muqaddas (in Palestine) and then his bodily ascent to the heavens occurred from there. The holy prophet used to do prayer before that as he prayed Allah in the form of prayer in the way to Beyt ul-Muqaddas and etc. as well, before the ascent starts! However the prayer was not obligatory until his ascent and first the number of obligatory prayers was much more but Moses --peace be upon him-- asked the holy prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- in heaven for him to ask Allah to reduce the duties of his people and thus the duties were reduced and the rest became Nafilah. These points can be found for example in the following Hadeeth:

> from: البرهان في تفسير القرآن، ج‏3، ص: 473-480
>
> علي بن إبراهيم، قال: حكى أبي، عن محمد بن أبي عمير، عن هشام بن سالم، عن
>   أبي عبد الله (عليه السلام) قال:
>
> ...
>
> و انتهيت إلى سدرة المنتهى، فإذا الورقة منها تظل أمة من الأمم، فكنت
>   منها كما قال الله تبارك و تعالى: قابَ قَوْسَيْنِ أَوْ أَدْنى‏ «6»
>   فناداني آمَنَ الرَّسُولُ بِما أُنْزِلَ إِلَيْهِ مِنْ رَبِّهِ «7»- و قد
>   كتبنا ذلك في سورة البقرة «8»- فقال رسول الله (صلى الله عليه و آله): يا
>   رب أعطيت أنبياءك فضائل فأعطني، فقال الله: قد أعطيتك فيما أعطيتك كلمتين
>   من تحت عرشي: لا حول و لا قوة إلا بالله، لا منجى منك إلا إليك. قال (صلى
>   الله عليه و آله): و علمتني الملائكة قولا أقوله إذا أصبحت و أمسيت:
>   اللهم إن ظلمي أصبح مستجيرا بعفوك، و ذنبي أصبح مستجيرا بمغفرتك، و ذلي
>   أصبح مستجيرا بعزك، و فقري أصبح مستجيرا بغناك، و وجهي الفاني البالي
>   أصبح مستجيرا بوجهك الدائم الباقي الذي لا يفنى. ثم سمعت الأذان، فإذا
>   ملك يؤذن لم ير في السماء قبل تلك الليلة، فقال: الله أكبر، الله أكبر.
>   فقال الله: صدق عبدي، أنا أكبر. فقال: أشهد أن لا إله إلا الله، أشهد أن
>   لا إله إلا الله. فقال الله تعالى: صدق عبدي، أنا الله لا إله غيري.
>   فقال: أشهد أن محمدا رسول الله، أشهد أن محمدا رسول الله. فقال الله: صدق
>   عبدي، إن محمدا عبدي و رسولي، أنا بعثته و انتجبته. ثم قال: حي على
>   الصلاة، حي على الصلاة. فقال الله: صدق عبدي و دعا إلى فريضتي، فمن مشى
>   إليها راغبا فيها محتسبا، كانت له كفارة لما مضى من ذنوبه. فقال: حي على
>   الفلاح، حي على الفلاح. فقال الله: هي الصلاح و النجاح و الفلاح. ثم أممت
>   الملائكة في السماء كما أممت الأنبياء في بيت المقدس، قال: ثم غشيتني
>   ضبابة فخررت ساجدا، فناداني ربي: أني قد فرضت على كل نبي كان قبلك خمسين
>   صلاة، و فرضتها عليك و على أمتك، فقم بها أنت في أمتك. فقال رسول الله
>   (صلى الله عليه و آله): فانحدرت حتى مررت بإبراهيم فلم يسألني عن شي‏ء،
>   حتى انتهيت إلى موسى، فقال: ما صنعت، يا محمد؟ فقلت: قال ربي: فرضت على
>   كل نبي كان قبلك خمسين صلاة، و فرضتها عليك و على أمتك. فقال موسى: يا
>   محمد، إن أمتك آخر الأمم و أضعفها، و إن ربك لا يرد عليك شيئا، و إن أمتك
>   لا تستطيع أن تقوم بها، فارجع إلى ربك فسله التخفيف لامتك. فرجعت إلى ربي
>   حتى انتهيت إلى سدرة المنتهى، فخررت ساجدا، ثم قلت: فرضت علي و على امتي
>   خمسين صلاة، و لا أطيق ذلك و لا امتي، فخفف عني. فوضع عني عشرا فرجعت إلى
>   موسى فأخبرته، فقال: إرجع، لا تطيق. فرجعت إلى ربي فسألته، فوضع عني
>   عشرا، فرجعت إلى موسى فأخبرته، فقال: إرجع، و في كل رجعة أرجع إليه أخر
>   ساجدا، حتى رجع إلى عشر صلوات. فرجعت إلى موسى فأخبرته، فقال: لا تطيق.
>   فرجعت إلى ربي فوضع عني خمسا، فرجعت إلى موسى فأخبرته، فقال: لا تطيق.
>   فقلت: قد استحييت من ربي، و لكن أصبر عليها. فناداني مناد: كما صبرت
>   عليها، فهذه الخمس بخمسين، كل صلاة بعشر، من هم من أمتك بحسنة يعملها
>   فعملها كتبت له عشرا، و إن لم يعملها كتبت له عشرا، و إن لم يعملها كتبت
>   له واحدة، و من هم من أمتك بسيئة فعملها كتبت عليه واحدة، و إن لم يعملها
>   لم أكتب عليه شيئا». فقال الصادق (عليه السلام): «جزى الله موسى عن هذه
>   الامة خيرا».

Also note that the ascent (actually this specific ascent, known as ) of the holy prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- has occurred before Hijrah as the trip started from Mecca!